# From date to day start time and end time in utc in specific timezone using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Hi I am  trying to find specific date to timezone, based on day start and end time in UTC, using momentJS.

For example:
I have one date : 2020-08-17 and its timezone is -5.

I would like to get day start and day end time in utc in this specific timezone.

I tried below code: But if I try other timezone, its always getting same data start and day end time as in utc.

```
date = 2020-08-21;
timezone=-5;//+10:30, +5:30
var start_date = moment.utc(moment(date).utcOffset(timezone).startOf('day').format()).format();
var end_date = moment.utc(moment(date).utcOffset(timezone).endOf('day').format()).format();
```

If I am missing anything please suggest,

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to say "in UTC in this specific time zone". UTC is essentially a time zone (albeit one defined by the lack of an offset from UTC). A time zone is more than just offset from UTC (for instance, DST changes) and time zones can share offset from UTC. As far as the code goes, it's not clear why you're formatting a moment as a string, then parsing that string as a moment, only to format it as a string again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question correctly, but it seems like the only problem is that you need to wrap the date in the `date` variable in quotes because it is supposed to be a string. Otherwise it just subtracts `2020 - 8 - 21` which is `1991`.

The code seems to run fine even if you change the timezone:

```
const moment = require('moment')

var date = "2020-08-21";
var timezone = -5; //+10:30, +5:30
var start_date = 
              moment.utc(
                moment(date)
                  .utcOffset(timezone)
                  .startOf('day')
              ).format("YYYY-MM-DD @ HH:mm:ss");
var end_date = 
              moment.utc(
                moment(date)
                  .utcOffset(timezone)
                  .endOf('day')
              ).format("YYYY-MM-DD @ HH:mm:ss");

console.log(start_date)
console.log(end_date)
```

[Run and edit this code online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/RecentOddMatter#index.js)

**Output:**

```
2020-08-20 @ 05:00:00
2020-08-21 @ 04:59:59
```

If the `timezone` variable is changed to `0` (UTC time), then the result is:

```
2020-08-21 @ 00:00:00
2020-08-21 @ 23:59:59
```

...which is indeed the start and end of the day.

Comment: How can i use these time zones in above code +10:30, +5:30

Comment: If you change the timezone variable to 10.5 (for +10:30) and 5.5 (for + 5:30) it should work because 10:30 is 10 hrs and 30mins which is 10.5 hrs and 5:30 is 5hrs 30mins which is 5.5 hrs

Comment: When the timezone us set to 10.5, then the response is: `start: 2020-08-20 @ 13:30:00 & end: 2020-08-21 @ 13:29:59`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
let myDate = new Date();

const timezoneOffset = moment(myDate).utcOffset();

moment(myDate).utc().add(timezoneOffset, 'minutes').startOf('day').format();
moment(myDate).utc().add(timezoneOffset, 'minutes').endOf('day').format();
```